# Regex to insert line breaks after specific series of token

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to convert a multi-line string, to insert line breaks `\n` after two final closing parenthesis occur in series, ie: `))` becomes `))\n`.

There is also likely to be a ')' just prior to the '))', effectively creating ')))'.

These two or three parenthesis may or may not be "spread out" by indeterminate lengths of whitespace, eg `))`, `)   )`, `)))`, `) ) )`, `))  )`, `)  ))` and so on.

I've tried the following:

```
//Example message
$message = '(item (name 286) (Index 31) (Image "item001") (class money coin) (code 4 110 0) (country 2) (plural 1) (buy 0))
(item(name 7904)(Index 7904) (specialty (Dex 10(defense 55)(hp 3500)(dodge 71)          ))

(item(name 7905)(Index 7905)(country 2) 
(level 80)(specialty(hp 3400)               )                               )

(item(name 7906)(Index 7906)(level 80)      (specialty(Str 10))                             ) ';

// Converts all lines into one line    
$message =  preg_replace("/[\r\n]*/","",$message); 

// Replace '))' with '))\n' - doesn't work.
$message =  preg_replace("/[)s+)]s*/","\n",$message); 

$InititemLines = explode("\n", $message);
for ($line = 0; $line < count($InititemLines); $line++) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line}</b> : " . $InititemLines[$line] . "<br />\n";
}
```

To convert all lines into one, I used:

```
$message = preg_replace("/[\r\n]*/","",$message);
```

Then, to replace `))` with `))\n`, I tried the following (but it doesn't work):

```
$message = preg_replace("/[)s+)]s*/","))\n",$message);
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
Line #0: (item (name 286) (Index 31) (Image "item001") (class money coin) (code 4 11 0 0) (country 2) (plural 1) (buy 0))
Line #1: (item(name 7904)(Index 7904) (specialty    (Dex 10)(defense 55)(hp 3500)(dodge 71)         ))
Line #2: (item(name 7905)(Index 7905)(country 2)(level 80)(specialty(hp 3400)       )           )
Line #3: (item(name 7906)(Index 7906)(level 80)     (specialty(Str 10))     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace the "))" at the end of ALL lines, in the case of line ending in `)))` or `))`:

`$message = Preg_replace( "\)?(\s*\)\s*\))", "$1\n", $message );`

This regex means

- find an optional single closing parenthesis ')'. We escape it as ')' as the parenthesis has special meanings in regex.  It's optional because of the trailing '?'.
- followed by 0 or more space characters denoted as '\s'.  0 or more denoted by '*',
- followed by another ')'
- followed by another 0 or more spaces,
- followed by another ')'
- Then we surround `\s*\)\s*\)` with a pair of '(' and ')' meaning "group this section, so we can reference it later".  We do this so we can replace it with `))\n`.

---

And then a more elegant solution *might* be (depending on your requirements...), to subsequently also strip any excess remaining spaces from before *every* ')':

`$message = preg_replace("(\)\s*)", "\)", $message);`

This regex means

- find an operning ')',
- followed by 0 or more spaces
- Grouped, so we can replace.

(In your example, I believe this will strip all the excess whitespace, while leaving the spaces in your strings alone).

Comment: what about if there a item have only )) not ))) like     (item (name 286)  (Index 31)(class money coin)(buy 0))
because when i try to use your way it dont replace it and when i try to make it only )) in preg_replace it dont replace the other item with have )))

Comment: is there anyway to select only the last )) and replace them to get it working with ))) and ))

Comment: yeah exactly thats why i looking for a way to select last )) only and replace it with ))\n

Comment: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\xampp\htdocs\testgot\index.php on line 21

Comment: @DragoN Sorry, that's because I hadn't escaped the literal '('s in my replacement string.  Your approach of using the `$1` match is (I suspect) computationally more expensive, but it's meaning is much more clear and thus I think a better way to do it.  Have updated my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you got it working fine with

```
$message = Preg_replace("/(\s*\)\s*\)?\s*\))/", "$1\n", $message );
```